# MGSplitViewController with Navigation Controller on detail side

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, uisplitviewcontroller

I am currently working on MGSplitViewController .So in this custom 
split view controller the root view controller is already present in side a navigation controller (MainWindow.xib) but my main aim is to get the MGSplitViewController working with a NavigationController in the details side also?

How can i do it, can anybody able to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do that in one project.

Put a UINavigationController into MainWindow.xib and have it contain your normal detail controller.  (You can either configure the detail controller directly or tell it to reference another xib file.)  Link the `detailViewController` outlet in MGSplitViewController to your detail navigation controller.

Let me know if some part of that is giving you trouble.

Comment: Hey @Phillip Mills, I saw that MGSplitViewController project does not have an updated for the past 2 years, do you have/know any fork that is not product specific and has been receiving updates? I am asking as it has more than 160 forks right now...

Answer (score 0):

Try this [APSplitViewController](https://github.com/SlavaBushtruk/APSplitViewController/) project from SlavaBushtruk's github.

This will anwser to your requirement.

Thanks